# Android device Hanging after first activity

Tags: java, android

I have two activities,One activity will click images in some time interval and process, after 120 seconds then the second activity will start automatically display with the results.I can run the app without any error but after two three times continues running the device gets stuck.

The logcat

> waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out (identity=3,status=0) cpu may be paged try again

after some time " SensorService dropping 1 event on the floor"

What I have to do.?

Comment: can i see ur code? paste code plz

Comment: Can you share your code.Please?

Comment: I am sorry i have more than 6000 lines of codes , I dont know where is the problem is. I can tell the work flow of my app First it will take a picture at the fifth second then an asynch task will start to process the image.then the second image will take at 15th second processing is same.After 110 seconds it will go to the second activity with a bundle of values and display the values over there

Comment: check your logcat values it will point you near to the buggy lines

Comment: debug it, put breakpoints and check the flow of your app, this will take you to the origin of problem

Comment: Did you check [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/XNuOmGjQyv0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by adding a sleep(Thread.Sleep(100)) before starting the second activity. Now it is working Fine